# TypeError: cp is not a constructor when running Angular 17 application via docker with npm run build

Tags: angular, typescript, docker, npm

I have created a Dockerfile to containerize my application, when I run `ng serve` as an entrypoint in the Dockerfile, the application works fine, the problem happens when I run `npm run build`.

**Here is the Dockerfile**:

[image: Dockerfile]

**This is the error that I'm getting**:

[image: Error in docker container]

Can someone help me with this?

I already tried to run npm run build command with the parameters --aot=false --build-optimizer=false, but no success.

Comment: Can you check your ng serve output for warnings? If I remember correctly "is not a constructor" can occur if there are problems with the dependency injection and decorators on services etc. Unfortunately it's been a long time since I encountered this.

Comment: This does not look like a build errror to me. Can you share your code? Your Angular code is probably the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Luiz, I couldn't reproduce the error, this the most basic configuration using some lines like your config files (example):

-APP_NAME_FOLDER/config/nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

-APP_NAME_FOLDER/dockerfile:

(I change the alpine node, to the ^18.13.0||^20.9.0 as angular v17 recommends to compatibility)

```
FROM node:18.13.0 as angular
WORKDIR /APP_NAME_FOLDER
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
COPY --from=angular /APP_NAME_FOLDER/dist/app_folder_name/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

-APP_FOLDER_NAME/angular.json:

(Assign custom port mapping by default '4200')

```
   "serve": {
      "options": {
        "port": 8383
      },
      "builder": ...
```

Finally just run the docker image (host port) 8383:80 and open "localhost:8383" and nginx/docker do the magic.

Comment: Thank you Joel, I changed the angular.json and the nginx.conf to this specifications, but unfortunately the error still remains.

Comment: Sorry Luiz, for couldn't help you, did you create an --ssr angular app or any special configuration?